# Download 55000 records for Blackberry OS 7

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have made a webworks app to download 55000 records from server.I intially used jquery with ajax to download the records.I am sending request for 500 records at a time So it will be 100 xmlhttprequests. It is in for loop but it is giving me 101 network error.Is there any strategy to download this many records.

Sample code given below.

```
for(var i=0,len=Provider.providerListData.length; i<len; i++)
{
  var params = "RequestedBy=";
      params += Provider.getPIN();//"2100000A"; 
      params += "&RequestedProviders=";
      params += Provider.providerListData[i];  

       var xobj = null;
   xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
   xobj.open('POST', Provider.uatUrl+"GetProviderData", true);
   xobj.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xobj.onreadystatechange=function() 
   {

 if (xobj.readyState==4) 

 {
     if (xobj.status==200)
     {

var provDataResponse = null;
provDataResponse = xobj.responseText;
if(provDataResponse)
{
var jsonresponse=null;
var jsonsubresponse = null;
if (provDataResponse != null) 
{

       try
{
jsonresponse = $.parseJSON(provDataResponse);
}
catch(e)
{
return;
}
getproviders(jsonresponse);//This function will add data into websql
}
}
}
else
     { 

alert("No response for Provider");
     }
}
}
   xobj.send(params);
}
```

Comment: How comes 100 requests and 101 errors? Anyway, you should serialize your connections, because I doubt you can open 100 simoultaneous connections at the same time.

Comment: Can you confirm that you can make 1x successful call to get 500 records?  Remove the loop logic for now and verify that this min requirement is working as expected.